# Upgrade to El Capitan, unable to use keyboard and trackpad after sleep

Tags: keyboard, sleep-wake, trackpad, macos

I have upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan. This version is stable enough but when I let my macbook pro 15" (2013) sleeping at night and reopening at the morning, keyboard and trackpad do not work anymore...

This issue never happened before and I tried to reset PRAM and SMC but nothing works.

I also tried to troubleshoot it by looking at logs and I spot these 2 lines:

```
06/10/15 09:25:20,000 kernel[0]: USBF:    21910.354    IOUSBHIDDriver(AppleUSBTCKeyboard)::RearmInterruptRead  returning error 0xe00002d8 (device is not ready), not issuing any reads to device
06/10/15 09:25:20,000 kernel[0]: USBF:    21910.379    IOUSBHIDDriver(AppleUSBMultitouchDriver)::RearmInterruptRead  returning error 0xe00002d8 (device is not ready), not issuing any reads to device
```

So I found that the IOUSBHIDDriver module was not load by the kernel, so I searched how to load it manually.

I did:

```
kextstat | grep -i "IOUSBHID*" (which return nothing, normal the module is unloaded)
kextload -b com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver
kextstat | grep -i "IOUSBHID*"
   65    3 0xffffff7f817f0000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver (900.4.1) 7180DE6A-7FF9-35D5-A78A-8C417A4BD45E <39 33 5 4 3 1>
```

Keyboard and trackpad still not working...

I check once again that the module is still loaded and it's not.

Am I alone with this problem ? Do you have any workaround waiting for an eventual patch from Apple ? Please do not tell me to reinstall.. It's not a real solution.

Thanks

Edit: today I didn't got the problem.. Let see tomorrow morning

Comment: I can`t type password and use trackpad after restart when the filevault is on. After i turn off filevault everything is ok. Please help. Macbook air 13 mid 2013, El Capitan 10.11

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. However, I can see all the "taps" I did in the diagnostic logs (even though the keyboard and trackpad weren't responding). They show under "MT Gesture Parser" from the message domain "com.apple.MultitouchSupport.gesturestats." I will disable multitouch support and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Today my macbook pro was stuck once again with this issue, but what I notice is that the 2 last days it was ok... I am wondering if it's related to VMWare Fusion drivers. I explain: During the 2 last days I have shut down my vm before going to sleep and at the morning everything was ok until this morning because I forget to switch my vm off yesterday night.. I will check if it's related.. Are you guys using a VM (VirtualBox or VMWare ?)..

Comment: I confirm that switching off VMWare tonight making my keyboard and trackpad working this morning. I guess that's an issue with VMWare kernel drivers... Tonight I will try to let it started to confirm that.

Comment: I have VMWare Fusion. I will keep an eye when this happens again and will let you know if shutting down Fusion solves the issue.

Comment: I have exact same problem - occured after upgrade to El Capitan and only when VMWare is left running, I use VMware alot and quite frequently forget to close it down before sleeping and 50% of the time it freezes on wake.  I have reported this to Apple which they are looking into although it looks like it is a VMWare problem

Comment: This is also occurring for me. El Capitan upgrade + VMWare Fusion 7.1.3 = non responsive keyboard. I can, however, unplug and replug a usb keyboard until it registers, then do a reboot.

Comment: What appears to be happening for me was that the mouse and keyboard were actually getting attached to the VM rendering control to the host OS (OSX) useless. The way to get around this is to plug in a keyboard and mouse, log in, save and reboot. Control to the trackpad and keyboard.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok I can confirm that the keyboard and trackpad are stuck after sleep when I let VMWare Fusion running... If you have something similar that's running in background it could be the problem.

To resolve it at the moment I pause all Virtual Machines and everything goes alright now.

This is probably related to kernel modules installed by VMWare but I can't find any clue...

Comment: What version of VMWare Fusion are you using? I'm am also using VMWare Fusion but I haven't upgraded to 8 yet (on 7.1.2) and am wondering if upgrading could fix.

Comment: I was on 6.x and now on 8.0.1 and it's still the same..

Comment: Bummer.  Allegedly, VMWare knows about this and is developing a fix - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7261273#29072453.  Here's hoping.

Comment: same problem to me too

Comment: I didn't think about VMWare Fusion, but indeed I did have it running when it went to sleep. Thanks for this find.

Comment: Is there some news about this? I have the newest VMWare Fusion 7, and have this problem now.

Comment: Not at all at the moment.. I am still waiting for a patch but nothing plan... I am still shutting down my vm every times I let my laptop sleeping... zZZzzZZzzZZ :)

Comment: Interesting. I get the same problem with keyboard/trackpad freezing after sleep, and I too use VMWare Fusion.

Comment: I have this same issue with OSX 10.11.4 and Vmware Fusion 7.1.3

Comment: I have this problem on a clean Mac Mini with El Capitan (10.11.3 thru 10.11.5 tried so far). No software but OS X on this machine. After sleeping for a long period, no USB, period. I can wake it with Screen Sharing from another system but the USB never comes back without a hard boot. Since I'm not running VMWare Fusion, not sure where to go.

Comment: Same problem using mac os 10.11.6 and vmfusion 7.1.0

Comment: I wonder if the same behavior could be caused by virtualbox. I'm seeing this behavior, but I use virtualbox instead of vmware.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reinstall, why not run the installer against a clean external USB drive. Does the trackpad work there? Does the trackpad work when you boot to the Recovery HD?

Those two things will tell you if you have a hardware issue (trackpad won't work anywhere) or a software issue (trackpad either will work in a new user account and not your specific user account) or a system issue (works in Recovery HD but not in your current system.

Based on where the problem lies, the solutions depend. You don't need a hardware repair if it's software and the software repair changes depending on what isolation steps pass.

Comment: Keyboard ans trackpad works after a restart, it's not a hardware issue.. It's bug due to this upgrade. Reinstalling has never been a solution.

Comment: But I will try to repair it by reinstalling the latest version without wiping the current one.